# htaccess: Redirect /index.php to root using ssl

Tags: .htaccess

I found plenty of examples without using https/ssl but nothing with.
Here's an example which I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/? [R=301,L]
```

All methods I found bring up this Error Message after opening mydomain.com/index.php:

> "Bad Request
>   Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
>   Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
>   Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please."

The browser is redirected to mydomain.com:443

I have another website on my server without a SSL-Certificate where I had no problem setting this up.

Do you guys have an idea?

Comment: So `http://example.com/index.php` needs to redirect to `https://example.com/` ?

Comment: exactly. as well as any https-links ending with index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule as your first rule in site root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /([^/]+/)*index\.(html|php)\ HTTP/ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.(html|php)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,NE,NC]
```

Comment: Perfect! This worked like a charm. Thank you very much

Comment: I just found a new problem which came out of this solution. I'm using Joomla and when I want to go into the backend nothing happens after I enter my login data. Is it possible to adjust the RewriteRule so that it doesn't redirect anything in the backend? So that example.com/administrator/index.php is allowed?

Comment: Now I can access the backend again but the original problem is back. example.com/index.php isn't redirected to example.com

I'm sorry that this is causing so much trouble

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located? It must be placed in site root NOT in any subdirectory of your site root

Comment: It's inside the root directory

Comment: I tried it but nothing changed. Backend is working but no redirection of index.php links. I made sure to delete all browser data before.

Comment: But meanwhile I searched for another solution and found this code:

`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /([^/]+/)*index\.(html|php)\ HTTP/`
`RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.(html|php)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

And this is working! The only downside is that the domain is static. Do you know whether it's possible to make the domain dynamic so that I can use the htaccess for multiple websites?

Comment: The Backend didn't work again with that code.
I altered the code myself a little based on your work and with this code it's all working perfectly:
`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /([^/]+/)*index\.(html|php)\ HTTP/ [NC]`
`RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.(html|php)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,NE,NC]`

Thanks for all the help dude